# Compare date with date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am facing this problem where SQL asked me to put aliases when I'm converting chars to date format, here is my query:

```
declare @dateTarget char(8) = '20130613'
declare @dateTarget2 char(8) = '20180608'
declare @dateNow as date = GETDATE()

IF CAST(CONVERT(DATE, 
                LEFT(@dateTarget, 4) + SUBSTRING(@dateTarget, 5, 2) + RIGHT(@dateTarget, 2))) >= CAST(@dateNow AS DATE) 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Target cannot be greater than DateNow.'
END
ELSE IF CAST(CONVERT(DATE, LEFT(@dateTarget2, 4) + SUBSTRING(@dateTarget2, 5, 2) + RIGHT(@dateTarget2, 2))) >= CAST(@dateNow AS DATE) 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Target2 cannot be greater than DateNow.'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'ok'
END
```

and these are the errors I get:

> Msg 1035, Level 15, State 10, Line 5
> Incorrect syntax near 'CAST', expected 'AS'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.
>
> Msg 1035, Level 15, State 10, Line 9
> Incorrect syntax near 'CAST', expected 'AS'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.

Comment: You're missing a type declaration in your `CAST` statements, which probably aren't even necessary as you're `CONVERT`ing to a date anyway.

Comment: delete the first `CAST(` on both conditions. also you don't need cast if you've already used CONVERT. you either use CAST or CONVERT as they're the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to convert string to date use [Cast or Convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms187928(v=sql.90))

```
select CAST(@dateTarget as date) 
select CONVERT(date, @dateTarget)
```

SQL Server can implicitly convert your string to date (though I recommend an explicit conversion)

```
declare @dateTarget  char(8) = '20130613'
declare @dateTarget2  char(8) = '20180608'
declare @dateNow as date = GETDATE()

IF @dateTarget >= @dateNow
BEGIN
    print 'Target cannot be greater than DateNow.'
END
ELSE IF @dateTarget2 >= @dateNow
BEGIN
    print 'Target2 cannot be greater than DateNow.'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    print 'ok'
END
```